# TFS automation with Python

Tags: python, tfs, automation

, can somebody provide some leads on how to automate TFS activities with python , I am looking for automating TFS tasks like creating workitems etc

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and [what types of questions can be asked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what types should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Microsoft TFS Python Library (TFS API Python client)](https://github.com/devopshq/tfs), following the instructions to do any actions based on your require.

You can reference below samples:

- [TFSClientAPI.py](https://github.com/Deunze/TFSClientAPI/blob/master/TFSClientAPI.py)
- [Python Script to Access Team Foundation Server (TFS) Rest API](http://techieroop.com/python-script-to-access-team-foundation-server-tfs-rest-api/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [dohq-tfs](https://pypi.org/project/dohq-tfs/) API for doing the automation.
It has most of the method for the automation + works well with local tfs and azure also